# Setting axis extent on Cartopy UTM projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I want to plot a set of UTM coordinates using Matplotlib (`v3.1.3`) and Cartopy (`v0.17.0`), and then manually set the extent of the axis. Normally I can do this with `axis.set_extent((left, right, bottom, top))`, but when I try to do this with UTM coordinates, I get an error message claiming that my coordinates are outside the permitted range. This also occurs when I literally copy and insert the current axis extent (using `axis.get_extent()`).

See the following minimal example:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Some random UTM coordinates
UTM = np.array([
    [328224.965, 4407328.289],
    [328290.249, 4407612.599],
    [328674.439, 4408309.066],
    [327977.178, 4407603.320],
    [328542.037, 4408510.581]
]).T

# Split into east and north components
east, north = UTM

# Create a canvas with UTM projection
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection=ccrs.UTM(zone="11S"))

# Plot coordinates
ax.scatter(east, north)

# Get the extent of the axis
extent = ax.get_extent()
# Attempt to set the axis extent
ax.set_extent(extent)

plt.show()
```

This raises the following exception:

> `ValueError: Failed to determine the required bounds in projection coordinates. Check that the values provided are within the valid range (x_limits=[-250000.0, 1250000.0], y_limits=[-10000000.0, 25000000.0]).`

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? Is there another way of setting the extent of the axis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line of code:

```
ax.set_extent(extent)
```

has an option `crs=None`, which translates to having `ccrs.PlateCarree()` as the default value. That means the values in degrees of longitude and latitude are expected in `extent` in the code.

To get it right, you must specify the correct crs:-

```
ax.set_extent(extent, crs=ccrs.UTM(zone="11S"))
```